# How to fetch all dates and time from string using JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datetime, trim

I'm trying to fetch all DateTime fields using JS/Jquery.

Currently I'm trying it with Regex, but failing miserably.

**INPUT:**

```
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 11:39:37 AM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 12:48:43 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 1:00:44 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 2:17:01 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:23:36 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:25:56 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:06:25 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:07:55 PM Valid Entry LC 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:28:19 PM Valid Exit Outside LC 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:30:06 PM Valid Entry Place1
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
9/10/2018 11:39:37 AM
9/10/2018 12:48:43 PM
9/10/2018 1:00:44 PM
9/10/2018 2:17:01 PM
9/10/2018 3:23:36 PM
9/10/2018 3:25:56 PM
9/10/2018 6:06:25 PM
9/10/2018 6:07:55 PM
9/10/2018 6:28:19 PM
9/10/2018 6:30:06 PM
```

**CURRENT LOGIC:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var txtIdAndName = str.replace(/[0-9]*\s[a-z,\s*]*/ig,"");
    var txtStatusAndPlace = txtIdAndName.replace(/[AM,PM]+\s[a-z,\s*]*/ig,"<br/>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txtStatusAndPlace;
}
```

Please do let me know if any more info is needed form my end.

Can use any Logic or method to achieve the task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match these substrings with

```
s.match(/\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M\b/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN8tY5/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits,
- `\/` - a slash (escaped since a regex literal notation is used with `/` as delimiters)
- `\d{1,2}\/\d{4}` - 1 or 2 digits, `/` and then 4 digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - (time pattern) 1 or 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:` and another 2 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[AP]` - `A` or `P`
- `M` - an `M` char
- `\b` - a word boundary.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "12345 User Name 9/10/2018 11:39:37 AM Valid Entry Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 12:48:43 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 1:00:44 PM Valid Entry Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 2:17:01 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:23:36 PM Valid Entry Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:25:56 PM Valid Entry Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:06:25 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:07:55 PM Valid Entry LC \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:28:19 PM Valid Exit Outside LC \n12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:30:06 PM Valid Entry Place1";
var rx = /\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M\b/g;
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + s.match(rx).join("<br/>") + "</pre>";
```

Comment: changing \d{2} to \d{1,2} in date will also match `12345 User Name 9/7/2018 12:48:43 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1`

Comment: @NambiMurugan Fair enough, I added  the minimum limit to the quantifier.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew This worked for me. Thanks a ton for the extra effort put in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex,

```
\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s*\d+:\d+:\d+\s*[AP]M
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rfrUrg/4/)

Comment: Note that `\s*?` will  yield the same result as `\s*` since `\d+` (pattern after) does not match a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Other users posted answer for using regex. But you can use another way instead of regex if structure of your string is constant.

Using javascript `.split()` to splitting string and using `.splice()` to selecting special part of result.

```js
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var newStr = str.trim().split("\n").map(function(text){
    return text.split(" ").splice(3, 3).join(" ");
}).join("\n");
console.log(newStr);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 11:39:37 AM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 12:48:43 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 1:00:44 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 2:17:01 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:23:36 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 3:25:56 PM Valid Entry Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:06:25 PM Valid Exit Outside Place1 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:07:55 PM Valid Entry LC 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:28:19 PM Valid Exit Outside LC 
12345 User Name 9/10/2018 6:30:06 PM Valid Entry Place1
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, even this option works great. Thanks for the reply